# When is 請じる used?

Tags: usage, verbs, word-usage

I read a novel, with the following sentence :

> 社会部記者と称する男は、快く支配人の部屋へ請じられた。

According to jisho.org,請じる means "to invite; to show (someone) in​". I searched online for examples of sentences where 請じる appears, but to my surprise I could not find any websites with it.

This makes me wonder, is 請じる very old or old-fashioned word ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 請じる/請ずる is indeed a rare literary verb, and I have not used it myself. Still, it's not an archaic word, and BCCWJ has at least 30 examples, most of which are used as part of 請じ入れる.